# How to show an image after having selected it from a drop down menu?

Tags: php

I have the following code to select my image from a drop down menu.

```
<select name="Image2">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <?php 
     $dir = "../files/images/product";//your path
    $dh  = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        $files[] = $filename;
  echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";  }
    sort($files);
 ?>

</select>
```

Is there a way I can preview the selected image?
I tried it like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $filepath.$filename ?>" />
```

However it doesn't show anything

Comment: Preview how? You've shown us code for outputting a `select`. You can't have images in there. Explain further how you intend the preview mechanism to work.

Comment: whats the $filepath you are giving?

Comment: the file path is the path to the selected file in this case ../files/images/product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you should try this..
this could help you out..

```
<select name="Image2" onChange="showImage(this.value)">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <?php 
     $dir = "../files/images/product";//your path
    $dh  = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        $files[] = $filename;
  echo "<option value='".$dir ."/". $filename . "'>" . $filename . "</option>";  }
    sort($files);
 ?>

</select>  

<div id="image_div"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
 function showImage(value)
 {
  var img = "<img src='"+value+"' />";
  document.getElementById('image_div').innerHTML = img;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <script>
       $('#attribute119').change(function () {
    var path=$('#filepath').val();
      $('#main').attr('src', path+'/'+ $('#attribute119 :selected').text() );
    });
    </script>

<img src="mainimage.jpg" id="main">
<select name="Image2" id="attribute119">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <?php 
     $dir = "../files/images/product";//your path
    $dh  = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        $files[] = $filename;
  echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";  }
    sort($files);
 ?>

</select> 
<input type=hidden id="filepath" value="<?php echo $filepath ?>"/>
```

Comment: It didn't work, what it did do is show an actual image box, however when selecting an image name front he menu it didn't show the image.

Comment: ok!. now edited the answer, check if it works. i used jquery!

Comment: lol! ok, never mind, neways, you sure you didnt forgot to include jquery library? and also, whats the output you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting a broken link image

Comment: I've sorted it the $dir = ../files/images/product/ needed the /. thanks for your help you made my day.

Comment: just tell me whether the jquery is working? did you try to debug it?